# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when i included <listener-class> to web.xml java

Tags: java, jboss6.x

Please, i don't find the reason for this error.

I created a class LogoutListener.java, this implements HttpSessionListener, with its two abstract methods: sessionCreated and sessionDestroyed.
And i added to the web.xml the respective listener tag:

...more code

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.seam</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Listeners used by application -->

<listener>
     <listener-class>com.akson.encuesta.session.helper.LogoutListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Restrict raw XHTML Documents</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>XHTML</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint />
</security-constraint>
```

... more code

When i delete the  tag, the server don't trhorw error, but when the tag is in web.xml the server thorw error (the next is part of log):

```
    EjbSynchronizations/local - EJB3.x Default Local Business Interface
        EjbSynchronizations/local-org.jboss.seam.transaction.LocalEjbSynchroniza
tions - EJB3.x Local Business Interface

12:16:12,550 INFO  [SessionSpecContainer] Starting jboss.j2ee:jar=demoencuesta06
.war,name=TimerServiceDispatcher,service=EJB3
12:16:12,551 INFO  [EJBContainer] STARTED EJB: org.jboss.seam.async.TimerService
Dispatcher ejbName: TimerServiceDispatcher
12:16:12,557 INFO  [JndiSessionRegistrarBase] Binding the following Entries in G
lobal JNDI:

        TimerServiceDispatcher/local - EJB3.x Default Local Business Interface
        TimerServiceDispatcher/local-org.jboss.seam.async.LocalTimerServiceDispa
tcher - EJB3.x Local Business Interface

12:16:12,559 WARN  [TimerServiceContainer] EJBTHREE-2193: using deprecated Timer
ServiceFactory for restoring timers
12:16:12,763 INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/demoencuesta06
12:16:12,806 ERROR [[/demoencuesta06]] Error configurando escuchador de aplicaci
¾n de clase com.akson.encuesta.session.helper.LogoutListener: java.lang.ClassNot
FoundException: com.akson.encuesta.session.helper.LogoutListener
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202) [:1.6.0_33]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [:1.6.0_33
]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190) [:1.6.0_33
]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306) [:1.6.0_33]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247) [:1.6.0_33]
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatInjectionContainer.newInstance(Tom
catInjectionContainer.java:278) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatInjectionContainer.newInstance(Tom
catInjectionContainer.java:264) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(Standar
dContext.java:3319) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3
828) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy
Internal(TomcatDeployment.java:294) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy
(TomcatDeployment.java:146) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeploy
ment.java:476) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118) [:6
.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:95) [:6.1.0.Fi
nal]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_3
3]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:39) [:1.6.0_33]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25) [:1.6.0_33]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [:1.6.0_33]
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatch
er.java:157) [:6.0.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96) [:6.0.0.G
A]
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88) [:6.0.0.GA]

        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.
java:271) [:6.0.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:670)
[:6.0.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java
:206) [:2.2.0.SP2]
        at $Proxy41.start(Unknown Source)       at org.jboss.system.microcontain
er.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:53) [:2.
2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installActio
n(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:41) [:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.sim
pleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.
2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.ins
tall(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install
(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(Abstra
ctControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(Serv
iceControllerContext.java:301) [:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractContr
oller.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(Abstra
ctController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementSta
teDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(Abstr
actController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(Abstr
actController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractContro
ller.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractContro
ller.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:67
1) [:6.1.0.Final (Build SVNTag:JBoss_6.1.0.Final date: 20110816)]
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:443)
[:6.1.0.Final (Build SVNTag:JBoss_6.1.0.Final date: 20110816)]
        at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java
:189) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.jav
a:102) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.jav
a:49) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.i
nternalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:63) [:2.2.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(
AbstractRealDeployer.java:55) [:2.2.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(Deployer
Wrapper.java:179) [:2.2.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(Deployer
sImpl.java:1832) [:2.2.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFi
rst(DeployersImpl.java:1550) [:2.2.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFi
rst(DeployersImpl.java:1571) [:2.2.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(Deployers
Impl.java:1491) [:2.2.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(Abstra
ctControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractContr
oller.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(Abstra
ctController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementSta
teDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(Abstr
actController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(Abstr
actController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractContro
ller.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractContro
ller.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.change(DeployersI
mpl.java:1983) [:2.2.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(Deployers
Impl.java:1076) [:2.2.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeploye
rImpl.java:679) [:2.2.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.p
rocess(MainDeployerPlugin.java:106) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$Delegate
Deployer.process(ProfileControllerContext.java:143) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.deploy(Profil
eDeployAction.java:151) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.installAction
Internal(ProfileDeployAction.java:94) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction
(InstallsAwareAction.java:54) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction
(InstallsAwareAction.java:42) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.sim
pleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.
2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.ins
tall(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install
(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(Abstra
ctControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractContr
oller.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(Abstra
ctController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementSta
teDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(Abstr
actController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(Abstr
actController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractContro
ller.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractContro
ller.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper$BasicPro
fileActivation.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:190) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper.start(Pr
ofileActivationWrapper.java:87) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activate
Profile(ProfileActivationService.java:215) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activate
(ProfileActivationService.java:159) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.ac
tivate(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:112) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.resolver.BasicResolverFactory$ProfileResolve
rFacade.deploy(BasicResolverFactory.java:87) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.st
art(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:91) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceB
ootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:132) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceB
ootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:56) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer.startBootstraps(A
bstractServer.java:827) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-6]
        at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer$StartServerTask.r
un(AbstractServer.java:417) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-6]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [:1.6.0_33]

12:16:12,899 ERROR [[/demoencuesta06]] Se ha saltado la instalaci¾n de escuchado
res de aplicaci¾n debido a error(es) previo(s)
12:16:12,900 ERROR [StandardContext] Error listenerStart
12:16:12,900 ERROR [StandardContext] Fall¾ en arranque del Contexto [/demoencues
ta06] debido a errores previos
12:16:12,917 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Start: name=jb
oss.web.deployment:war=/demoencuesta06 state=Create mode=Manual requiredState=In
stalled: org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: URL file:/D:/jboss-6.1.0.F
inal/server/default/deploy/demoencuesta06.war/ deployment failed
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy
Internal(TomcatDeployment.java:325) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy
```

I use Eclipse Indigo, Jboss, Seam, RichFaces

thank you

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the replies. I just fixed the problem. The files .class were being generated in WEB-INF/dev , and when the jboss did the deploy it searched the .class in WEB/classes , but in this last directory only contained the .class of the model, anymore. I modified build-dev.properties, deleting actin.dir ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `ClassNotFoundException` implies that the fully qualified name for the given class wasn't a valid reference (in short: the class was not found by the classloader). There are several things you should check:

- Is the class in your project?
- Is the fully qualified name correct? (to be sure: *right click* > *copy qualified name*)
- Are the proper jars referenced correctly?
- Are there any errors in the build path?
- If you provide the class inside a jar that is a library, is it properly added to the project?
- If you package everything in an EAR, is this project (module) part of it? Did you check the deployment assembly to ensure the jars are loaded correctly? Are the shared libraries being correclty provided to each module inside the EAR?

Comment: Thank you Gamb,  I answer all the question, and my doubt is in the second, the path when i do " right click > copy qualified name " is /demoencuesta06/src/hot/com/akson/encuesta/session/helper/LogoutListener.java  
and i wrote in web.xml 
<listener>
<listener-class> com.akson.encuesta.session.helper.LogoutListener   </listener-class>
</listener>

Answer (score 1):

This error appears because you don't have the class file for `com.akson.encuesta.session.helper.LogoutListener` on your classpath. Check the `.jar`s in your project for this file or add it if you don't have it.

If this is your own class in your project, try recompiling the project in Eclipse.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, What .jars would be for this file? , and I recompiled the project, i have a new .war, and the error continue....

Comment: I don't know. It looks like your own file, not publicly available.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that `com.akson.encuesta.session.helper.LogoutListener` is in the classpath of your application.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the deployment directory where your application is getting deployed. Check if your class is present in WEB-INF/classes or at least inside any jar in WEB-INF/lib folder.
If you are using eclipse WTP plugin to deploy your application, you must check whether your application files are correctly getting deployed. Sometimes the runtime doesn't get sync properly with project output files.